# Clover can't instrument UTF-8 source

Tags: java, ant, character-encoding, clover

I am setting up Clover in an existing project. It fails to instrument a line of source:

```
if ((character != 'ö') && (character != 'ø') && (character != 'ü')
```

With the error:

```
> /path/to/MyClass.java:13:33:expecting ''', found 'Â'
```

So it seems to me that the instrumentation has attempted to parse the source byte by byte and can't understand why the char has not terminated after 1 byte.

Is there a way to tell Clover to parse in UTF-8 via Ant?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the maven plugin? Or a different method? The maven-clover2-plugin has an encoding configuration option: http://docs.atlassian.com/maven-clover2-plugin/3.1.7/setup-mojo.html#encoding

Comment: I'm using gradle, which delegates to ant.

Comment: Ant task has such option as well, e.g.: <clover-instr encoding="UTF-8"/>